# Run external file via command line importing Django apps

Tags: python, django, django-views

Simple question as that, but I can't find the answer.

I have a python script located into one of my Django apps - in my django Project.

I'm using PyCharm IDE and local development works fine, I run scripts using CTRL + ALT + R, as below:

```
from location.crawlers.crawler_cities import *
```

The problem is, when I have to do it in my Live Server, I have no clue how to import it, I'm doing this:

1. Activate virtualenv
2. Go to project folder
3. Run python (Here I think is the problem is running the python outside my virtualenv not the python installed in my virtualenv itself)
4. from location.crawlers.crawler_cities import *

I then, finally I get this error

ImportError: No module named location.crawlers.crawler_cities

Any ideas how can I run this in Live Server?

Comment: place it in the same folder or make an app or make a middleware

Comment: If your app directory is in sys path, you can create a directory called something like `scripts` and create an empty file `__init__.py` in there, then do `from appname.scripts import crawler_cities`. The `__init__.py` is to make your `scripts` directory a package so you can import from. By the way, `import  *` is not good practice because you might run into import issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to append the route of your django project to your PYTHONPATH, before you call the import.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/project')
```